# Add data to POST on every $http request with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send custom POST parameter (CSRF token) on every $http post request on AngularJS. I tried with an interceptor, it works but is sending parameter as GET, and I need to send as POST.

Basically I need something like $.ajaxSetup() on jQuery.

**$http request:**

```
App.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $window, $http)
{
    $scope.email = undefined;
    $scope.password = undefined;

    $scope.login = function() {
        var request = $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: gurl + 'user/login',
                // headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest'},
                data: $.param({email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password})
            });
        request.success(function(data) {
            if(angular.equals(data.status, 'success')) {
                $window.location.href = gurl + 'dashboard';
            }
            else {
                noty('error', data.msg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Interceptor**

```
App.factory('csrfInterceptor', function($q, $location, $injector)
{
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
            // do something on success

            config.param = config.param || {};
            config.param.csrf_token = $("input:hidden[name='csrf_token']").val();

            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: do want send the token as a header ???

Comment: @sachilaranawaka, not really, I want to send token as POST. So what I want is to add token on every http post request I made.

Comment: You can use `$httpProvider.interceptors`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko yeah, im using `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('csrfInterceptor');` but as I said, is sending data as GET, and I need to send as POST.

Comment: On `request` in interceptor use `param` for *GET* and `data` for *POST*

Comment: If you wont set set it globally, another approach is using transformRequest (optional with ngResource)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko you mean using config.data instead of config.param? Because it doesn't work :(

Comment: @bigless thanks! Finally im using transformRequest adding key/value pair to data :)